# While covering the Queen, what happens if I pocket only an opponent's coin?

Tags: carrom

I pocket the Queen and then, while covering, pocket only an opponent's coin instead of my own. Both players still have more coins left on the board. Does the Queen count as being covered by the opponent or will it be put back on the board?

Comment: I've edited this to clarify its meaning, which isn't covered by the other linked question.

Answer (score 3):

No, you fail to cover the Queen so your turn ends and the Queen is replaced in the centre of the board.